# Multiple count distinct on sql Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

Im facing a issue with multiple count on a single query.

Im using SQL server 2014 with very high end configuration server. i.e, 224 GB RAM, 4k PIOPS.

Since I have created CLUSTERed COLUMN STORE index on tables, now i can't create any indexes.

Please find my query. fct_sale_line has 1.75 B rows and I have created CLUSTERED COLUMN STORE index on it.

```
SELECT dim_customer.gender_code,
       gender,
       date_key,
       COUNT(DISTINCT fct_sale_line.CUSTOMER_CODE),
       COUNT(DISTINCT fct_sale_line.customer_key),
       SUM(sale_net_val)
FROM dbo.fct_sale_line fct_sale_line,
     dbo.dim_customer dim_customer,
     dbo.dim_product dim_product,
     dbo.dim_store dim_store
WHERE fct_sale_line.date_key >= 20120126
AND   fct_sale_line.date_key <= 20130126
AND   department_code IN ('400','500','600','700','800')
AND   fct_sale_line.customer_key = dim_customer.customer_key
AND   fct_sale_line.product_key = dim_product.product_key
AND   fct_sale_line.store_key = dim_store.store_key
GROUP BY dim_customer.gender_code,
         gender,
         date_key
ORDER BY gender;
```

the query is never ending. its running .. running .. running and running.

But when i removed one of COUNT(DISTINCT ) and kept another, then it is fetching the result in 1 min's. Can any one help me resolve this issue.

Even i have tested with the single table. please see time taken by each query.

```
SELECT date_key,
       SUM(sale_net_val),
       COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.fct_sale_line fct_sale_line
WHERE fct_sale_line.date_key >= 20120126
AND   fct_sale_line.date_key <= 20130126
GROUP BY date_key;
```

Took only 1 Sec's to fetch the result.

```
SELECT date_key,
       SUM(sale_net_val),
       COUNT(1),
       COUNT(DISTINCT fct_sale_line.CUSTOMER_CODE)
FROM dbo.fct_sale_line fct_sale_line
WHERE fct_sale_line.date_key >= 20120126
AND   fct_sale_line.date_key <= 20130126
GROUP BY date_key;
```

Took 29 Sec's, but still acceptable(b'z of count distinct).

```
SELECT date_key,
       SUM(sale_net_val),
       COUNT(1),
       COUNT(DISTINCT fct_sale_line.CUSTOMER_CODE),
       COUNT(DISTINCT fct_sale_line.CUSTOMER_KEY)
FROM dbo.fct_sale_line fct_sale_line
WHERE fct_sale_line.date_key >= 20120126
AND   fct_sale_line.date_key <= 20130126
GROUP BY date_key;
```

--Never Ending(Waited for 45 Min's)

Can anyone let me know is it a known issue in the sql server 2014.

Regards

Noor

Comment: Try using `JOIN` with an `ON` clause instead of selecting from related tables like this. Otherwise SQL will first perform a cross join on all the tables before filtering the results with the `WHERE` clauses. Try reading Aaron's post: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: No use at all. Even i have tried with single table. Even i have rewrite the query in different manner which took around 60 to 90 seconds.

Comment: But i dont want to change the query as my application need lot of changes. Let me know if it is bug in sql server 2014.

Comment: While searching in net i got some integresting thing about the sql server 2014 vs 2012. http://www.nikoport.com/2013/08/16/clustered-columnstore-indexes-part-19-batch-mode-2012-limitations-updated/

Comment: @NoorAhmed what happens when you use joins instead of where clause? what's the timing?

Comment: Have you compared the estimated SQL plans between the fast and the never-ending queries?  That should help give you some clue...

Comment: @Paolo, i have tried with joins, but of no use. Waited for around 30 min's and i didn get the result. I guess when we didn get the result from a single table(Fct_sale_line) then no chance of getting from joins also. Any other commnets will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Clustered Columnstore Indexes are extremely effective in the terms of the IO, so that alone should help you avoiding reading unnecessary data.

Without seeing the execution plan I would guess that your problem might be lying in the Execution mode:
check on your execution plan if your Hash Match (Aggregate) (group by parameters for example) are running in the Batch Mode and if you are Spilling on the disk.

The following query for the ContosoRetailDW will take some amount of time to run, because of the Spilling which occurs in Row Mode at the Hash Match (second line after eager spool):

```
select count( distinct StoreKey ) as 'Distinct Stores'
, count( distinct CustomerKey ) as 'Distinct Customers'
, count( distinct CurrencyKey ) as 'Distinct Currencies'
from dbo.FactOnlineSales sales
    inner join dbo.DimPromotion prom
        on sales.PromotionKey = prom.PromotionKey
where prom.DiscountPercent = 0
group by sales.LoadDate, sales.ProductKey
```

Sorry, I can't put an execution plan image because of my low reputation – it is being blocked right now.

You might need to run a more selective query (with more precise predicates),
you can increase memory grants by modifying your query,
and also you can use the Segment Elimination Technic, which should help quite a lot for distinct counts: http://www.nikoport.com/2014/04/16/clustered-columnstore-indexes-part-29-data-loading-for-better-segment-elimination/

Best regards,
Niko